# FormTokenField passing objects to value property

Tags: block-editor

[In the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/form-token-field/) it is noted that value property can be "...an array of strings or objects to display as tokens in the field. If objects are present in the array, they must have a property of value."

And there is an example of how these objects should look like.

However, when I copy the exact same object, remove the unnecessary properties, and pass it as initial FormTokenField value, "title" property is ignored. For example:

```
const initial = [
    {
        value: '29654',
        title: 'Post Title'
    }
];

const [ selectedContinents, setSelectedContinents ] = useState( initial );
```

When using the code above, I would expect to get the "Post Title" in the FormTokenField on page reload, but I still get "29654".

What I need to do is to save and read both post title and ID, but to show only the post title in the FormTokenField.

Comment: Could you include the code in which you're actually using the `<FormTokenField>` component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, the "title" which the documentation refers to is a `title` attribute on the `<span>` which is rendered for the token, which is to say that the token

```js
{
  value: '29654',
  title: 'Post Title'
}
```

will (rhetorically) render as

```html
<span title="Post Title">29654</span>
```

In order to display "Post Title" as the inner text in the span, it must be used as the `value` of the token - or the value must be transformed into a post name via a callback passed to the `displayTransform` prop.

However, the callbacks passed in to the `displayTransform` prop only receives the token `value` string as an argument - so you will still require some form of external data management or mapping in order to work with more complex values. `<FormTokenField>` simply won't maintain state for any sort of complex values on it's own.